# How can I convert G.729 or G.711 files to WAV?

Tags: audio-conversion

I need to convert G.729 or G.711 files to WAV/WMA/MP3 or any other format which can be played in for example Windows Media Player.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The [command in this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/829998/167207) will work as long as the extension of the file matches the codec, ie .g729 or .g711. If the file is not the exact extension, like Mitel Audiotex files with extensions .n08a or .n64u, you need to tell FFMPEG what the file type is using -f .

```
ffmpeg -f g729 -i <yourFile> <yourNewFile.mp3>
```

You can further reduce the risk of errors by identifying the codec using -acodec and set the audio sampling frequency using -ar

```
ffmpeg -f g729 -i <yourFile> -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8000 <yourNewFile>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using ffmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org). It's widely used so you find lots of documentation, it's available for Linux, Win, Mac and (mostly) under LGPL/GPL.

You may try using:

```
ffmpeg -i <yourFile> <yourNewFile.mp3>
```

Comment: But do you know that this tool works with these file types? Others seem to say it doesn't, meaning this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have many you can do them online here: [Online audio conversion tool - Guru Audio Convert](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tools/audio_conversion.php)

There is also a linux command line tool, if you have the right codecs installed: http://redice.krisk.org/